# How to compare 2 strings with different encoding and different unicode characters in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, character

I need to make an international accreditation validation by name and surname. But the problem is, that i need to return TRUE even if characters are different.

EXAMPLE:

```
    $str1 = 'Bożydar Kamiński';
    $str2 = 'BOZYDAR KAMINSKI';
    // I need this to be TRUE
    if ($str1 == $str2) {
        echo 'YOUR BUNNY WROTE';
    }
```

Is there is some php default functions to convert UTF-8 string with unicode characters (str1) to a plain latin characters?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the possible differences regarding the UTF-8 encoder, you can create your own decoder. You can create a table with all possible strange characters and in the function you should perform the comparison and then exchange for the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$coll = Collator::create('');
$coll->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);
var_dump(0 == $coll->compare(
    'Bożydar Kamiński',
    'BOZYDAR KAMINSKI'
)); // bool(true)
```